# Info Plist Does Not Contain All Key-Values Pairs

Tags: xcode, info-plist

### A) What I Expect:

In Swift, I have learned that in order to access values of my Info plist, I have to:

1. *right click* on my **Info** file
2. *select* **Open As** and **Source Code** (this will show the plist in XML format)
3. *find* the **key** I am interested in in the now as XML presented Info plist file
4. *access* the value I am interested in using the **key** I have looked up in the XML like this:

```swift
let value = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String ?? "n.a."
```

### B) What I Get:

- The problem I am facing is that my Info plist does not contain the key-value pairs for things like version number or build number (see below).
- For example `CFBundleShortVersionString` is not listed in there. Note that the command under point 4 above still works!
- Opening a **brand new Xcode project**, using **Swift 5** and **Xcode 14.3.1**, my Info plist opened as XML look looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Test</key>
    <string>TestValue</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

### C) My Question:

Could someone tell me how I would find the proper **key-value pairs** for all my system configurations?

Comment: In Xcode, don't open as XML, but as plist, go near a key, and tap on "+" and select the desired information `Bundle version string (short)` I guess... It will create then a `<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key><string>something</string>` and you can use `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` to bind the value instead of "something"

Comment: @Larme thanks for you response. However, I could not get it to work this way. The thing is that the values do exists if I simply open up the Info pilist in Xcodes GUI. However, this does not give me the keys I need in order to refer to them in my code. Adding the same key-value pair as you suggest does not work for me - they still do not show up in the XML. In fact, it seems as if Xcode overrides my input if I try to set them a second time.

Comment: You can add it manually then in XML? Since it's a Key/value, yes, if you add another one, it won't be a valid dictionary;

Comment: @Larme yes I could add it manually to the XML. But also this does not bring back all the other key-value pairs that exist.